# Visual Studio 2017 installation fails with package install error

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, visual-studio-2017

I am attempting to install visual studio 2017.
I get an error after the installation "Setup Operation Failed"

Below is the install output log.

The log reports this step failed:

```
Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebDeploy.Msi,version=15.0.26430.16,chip=x64' failed to install.
```

Log:

```
The product failed to install the listed workloads and components due to one or more package failures.

Incomplete workloads
    .NET Core cross-platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools,version=15.0.26323.1)
    ASP.NET and web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb,version=15.0.26412.1)

Incomplete components
    ASP.NET and web development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web,version=15.0.26323.1)
    Web Deploy (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.WebDeploy,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Windows Communication Foundation (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Wcf.Tooling,version=15.0.26208.0)

You can search for solutions using the information below, modify your selections for the above workloads and components and retry the installation, or remove the product from your machine.

Following is a collection of individual package failures that led to the incomplete workloads and components above. To search for existing reports of these specific problems, please copy and paste the URL from each package failure into a web browser. If the issue has already been reported, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue has not been reported, you can create a new issue where other people will be able to find solutions or workarounds.

Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebDeploy.Msi,version=15.0.26430.16,chip=x64' failed to install.
    Search URL: https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebDeploy.Msi;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=1720
    Impacted workloads
        .NET Core cross-platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools,version=15.0.26323.1)
        ASP.NET and web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb,version=15.0.26412.1)
    Impacted components
        ASP.NET and web development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web,version=15.0.26323.1)
        Web Deploy (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.WebDeploy,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Windows Communication Foundation (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Wcf.Tooling,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Log
        C:\Users\jawierzb\AppData\Local\Temp\2\dd_setup_20170731130217_255_Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebDeploy.Msi.log
    Details
        MSI: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebDeploy.Msi,version=15.0.26430.16,chip=x64\webdeploy_x64.msi, Properties:  REBOOT=ReallySuppress 
        Return code: 1720
        Return code details: There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A script required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.
```

It references a detail log file which is too large to fit here but I am scanning it trying to find anything relevant.

Comment: Pop open the log file and see which package ID failed to install. It's usually within the last few lines of the end of the log. I run into this all the time with VS (it's a huge pain). Once you locate the ID you can find the package in the temp folders and then try to install it manually.

Comment: Running MSI manually fails with an error. Event viewer gave a little more details, I'm doing some investigation on that then will report back

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this issue turned out to be a windows problem. The WMI repository was corrupted. I re-installed windows and the install succeeded.